# Sort(A.end(), A.begin()); giving segmentation fault in c++ STL

Tags: stl, segmentation-fault

[See the code, why decreasing order sort is not working?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47EA5.png)

[This error is coming: Segmentation fault](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRtuU.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Why? how will you understand without image?

Comment: Code (and those errors) are **text**. There is no valid reason to post those images instead of (formatted) text. Just read the page linked in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

you can just sort normally and then reverse it
as below

```
sort(A.begin(), A.end);
reverse(A.begin(), A.end());
```

simple

**Reason for error:**
i think reason for fault is
internally method tries to take the first and second argument as the starting as ending index to sort
it works like this it starts taking first index then it tries to increment by one in every comparison for min or max then then check if the index incremented is less than the second argument or not

where as here in you case
you gave the indexs in reverse which lead to failure of sorting

Comment: can you sort it in reverse without using reverse(A.begin, A.end), and by using sort(A.begin(), A.end()); and doing some changes in the parameters we are passing in the sort() function!??

Comment: `std::sort(A.begin(), A.end(), std::greater<int>())` would sort in descending order, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: ok, consider i have used
using namespace std;

and what is the meaning of this greater<int>()?
Will you please explain!!